# Not getting result when pushing into a list

Tags: coffeescript

I have this coffeescript code

```
    emails = []
    for mail in profile.emails
        emails.push mail.value
    if !emails[0]
        options =
            url: "https://api.github.com/user/emails?access_token=" + accessToken
            headers:
                "user-agent": "zmgc.net"
                Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3"
        request options, (error, response, body)->
            unless error
                try
                    user_emails = JSON.parse body
                    email = user_emails[0].email
                    console.log email
                    emails.push email
                catch ex
                    return done(ex)
```

When I get into the `if !emails[0]` and try to push the value to the emails list, I get an empty string!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

the call is asynchronous so in my code this comes last and it is why i could not get it. it is fixed now.